# How to check that RLS filter will propagate?

Tags: powerbi, ssas, powerbi-desktop, row-level-security

I have the below model:
[image]

And I am unsure if my RLS propagates correctly…

The model has 2 regular facts **FactRevenue** and **FactSales**  (I cut them from the screenshot, just for clarity) and it also has **Aggregated Revenue** (shown in the screenshot).

I have two roles, on **Employee Current** where I have the next RLS:

ROLE1:

=[NT Username] = USERNAME()

ROLE2:

=[TeamLeadID] IN SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER('Employee Current','Employee Current'[NT UserName] = USERNAME()),"ID",[ID])

Engagement Role is an UNPIVOT of Employee (each Employee can have up to 5 different roles…) (Therefore it is 1:*)

My questions are:

- will my RLS filter in **Employee Current** flow to **Engagement Role** and then flow to **WBS**, and then flow to **FactSales** ?
- will my RLS filter in **Employee Current** flow to **AgProfitCenter** and then flow to **Aggregated Revenue**?

Answer (score 0):

In Powerbi Desktop go to Modeling "View as". Check and verify if everything works as expected.

[image]

Or use DaxStudio. Expand Advanced Options and type "Effective User Name"

[image]

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I consume from SSAS, so I can only "see" the model, "view as" is grayed out.

Comment: You can try DaxStudio. Advanced Options -> Effective User Name;